# How to return zero on a referenced cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've done this in the past, but can't get it to work.

I need the outcome to be zero rather than a blank cell.

Here is my formula in cell `F47`:

```
=IF(E319>0,('2023 Labor Costs'!$M168/12),"")
```

- `E319` is zero. the result in `F47` is blank.
- If `E319` is greater than zero, then the formula executes properly.

Comment: Since your FALSE value is " " i.e. BLANK ,, the formula returns BLANK ,, replace "" with 0 !!

Comment: Thank you Rajesh!

Comment: ,,,, you are most welcome,,, & keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(--(E19>0)=1,('2023 Labor Costs'!$M168/12),IF(ISBLANK(E19),"","0"))`